# CoreData: How to count number of rows and other aggregate functions

Tags: core-data, ios5, xcode4.2

If I open my Core Data database with sqlite3, I can run the following SQL commands and get the results needed.

```
sqlite> select count(*) from ZPROFILEITEMS;
15
```

The same goes for the SUM() function:

```
sqlite> select SUM(ZPROFILEITEMSSONGORDER) from ZPROFILEITEMS; 
120
```

How can I accomplish the same in Core Data?

Thanks in advance

-Paul

Answer (score 0):

For counting you can always use this method on the context

```
- (NSUInteger)countForFetchRequest:(NSFetchRequest *)request error:(NSError **)error
```

This will return the number of fetched objects if core data had to fetch them.

For the sum method I guess one way would be to fetch the objects and to loop manually through them ...

Comment: I found this that should do what I'm looking for: [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html)